# Getting incomplete messages when trying to read from Arduino with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, arduino, communication

I'm having some issues with arduino. In class, we are learning arduino/java communication. Thus, we are asked to interpret bytes sent from the arduino and write it out in the console of eclipse as whatever type the "key" of the message tells us to write it in.

As of now, I'm just testing input streams, but I can't seem to get a complete message ever. This is what I'm doing:

```
    public void run() throws SerialPortException {
    while (true) {
        if (port.available()) {     //code written in another class, referenced below
            byte byteArray[] = port.readByte(); //also code written in another class, referenced below 
            char magicNum = (char) byteArray[0];
            String outputString = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; ++i) {
                char nextChar = (char) byteArray[i];
                outputString += Character.toString(nextChar);
            }
            System.out.println(outputString);
        }

    }
}
```

below is the code from the other class that is used in the above code

```
public boolean available() throws SerialPortException {
    if (port.getInputBufferBytesCount() == 0) { 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public byte[] readByte() throws SerialPortException {
    boolean debug= true; 
    byte bytesRead[] = port.readBytes();
    if (debug) {
        System.out.println("[0x" + String.format("%02x", bytesRead[0]) + "]");
    }
    return bytesRead;
}
```

Comment: i forgot to mention, the input stream i input from the arduino interface is "this is a test" and i get outputs like "nullthis is a" and "nulla test" or just "null"

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to know *when* data is going to be available, nor *whether* input data is going to be available all at once rather than in several chunks.

This is a *quick and dirty fix*:

```java
public void run() throws SerialPortException {
    String outputString = "";
    while (true) {
        if (port.available()) {
            byte byteArray[] = port.readByte();

            for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; ++i) {
                char nextChar = (char) byteArray[i];

                if (nextChar == '\n') {
                    System.out.println(outputString);
                    outputString = "";
                }

                outputString += Character.toString(nextChar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The declaration of `outputString` is moved out, and it is assigned `""` so to get rid of that ugly `null` on *standard output*.

Each time `\n` is encountered in the *serial input* data, the content of `outputString` is printed on *standard output* first and cleared afterwards.